# Laravel collection formatting key to field

Tags: php, laravel, collections, laravel-collection

I have a laravel collection that has this format:

```
{
  "24385528032901": [
    {
      "time": "2020-06-30T22:30:00.000000Z",
      "conso_prod": "Prod",
      "meter_id": "24385528032901",
      "delta": "0",
    },
    {
      "time": "2020-06-30T23:00:00.000000Z",
      "conso_prod": "Prod",
      "meter_id": "24385528032901",
      "delta": "2",
    }
  ], 
  "24385528032777": [
    {
      "time": "2020-06-30T22:30:00.000000Z",
      "conso_prod": "Prod",
      "meter_id": "24385528032777",
      "delta": "0",
    },
    {
      "time": "2020-06-30T23:00:00.000000Z",
      "conso_prod": "Prod",
      "meter_id": "24385528032777",
      "delta": "5",
    }
  ], etc.
}
```

I'm having an hard time converting it to a chartJS linechart graph format:

```
[
    [
        'label' => '24385528032901',
        'data' => $measures->map->delta,
    ], [
        'label' => '24385528032777',
        'data' => $measures->map->delta,
    ],
]
```

I know there is a collection method to do this, but can't find it anymore. Anyone ?

Comment: What is this `$measures->map->delta`? Is this some other variable you have or is it something else?

Comment: map->delta is a shortcut of a map function returning delta field only

Comment: What about just iterating over the collection, getting the data creating an array with that, and pushing it to the another parent array?

Comment: I don't like to use loops. There is a more elegant way to do it

Answer (score 0):

If i got your question right and you want to get `meter_id` and `delta` as `label` and `data` you can get `meter_id` and `delta` fields only from your collection then use collection's map helper to map these fields to your new field names like so

```
Model::get(['meter_id', 'delta'])->map(function (Model $model) {
   return [
       'label' => $model->meter_id,
       'data' => $model->delta,
   ];
})->toArray()
```